# Hidden Form Fields

Tags: html, forms

Is there a way to post some values in a form without using hidden fields?

The user should not be able to read these values by checking the DOM.

Comment: This is really vague. Please give an example of what you intend to do, or you will continue to get varying, confused answers.

Comment: I am developing some thing like this site. https://www.psd2html.com/order-now.html. Each time user adds a feature, my total payment changes. Now my final payment is stored in a hidden field and users can change that by changing dom and submit with the result wrong payment goes to payment gateway. I don't understand how the reference site is doing it.

Comment: You can always make a double check in your server side coding. Like say you would know what items have been ordered, and you also get the price from your request. Now to ensure that the request was not tampered, you again calculate the amount for the ordered item at your server-side, and match it with the value obtained from the request. If they match, then the value was not modified, else you can return an error or any customized message you want..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use hidden fields for posting data. But if you want that the user should not be able to read the values set in hidden field, you can encrypt the value before setting in the hidden field and then set it.

In this way nobody except you, who knows how to decode the value, would be able to read it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a payment page for my site and I don't want to take any risks for form tampering. Hackers may decode the payment values.

Comment: @Umar: Well, you may be right, but there are many encryption techniques which you can use... Or possibly you can design your own custom encryption technique which ensures that its only you who knows how to decode the encrypted data..

Comment: @Umar: Based on the comment you added to your question, let me explain. There are two alternatives 1) You can move your logic of calculating the total amount to your server-side coding. 2) You recalculate the amount at your server-side based on the items ordered. This would be a better solution as it always ensures that the requests are not modified before they reach your server.. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

AJAX can post any values you like, whether or not they appear in the form.

Comment: Ajax can post the data, but it still is not secure. Anyone with a mind to sniff the traffic will have access to what was in the ajax request.

Comment: HTTPS is easy. And the asker never said anything about "secure".

Answer (score 0):

Well, whatever method you use the data is visible. The way sensitive data can be handled 'safely' on a public webpage is twofold.

1. Encrypt the data, as other poster mentionned.
2. Use ssl ( https:// ) for the pages you want secured. This prevents any 3rd party from sniffing the traffic generated by your users requests.

With these 2 simple steps properly implemented, the data, though not 100% secure ( nothing is secure on the net ), it is a lot harder to attain.

Answer (score 0):

Using this two way passworded encryption class

http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/showsource.php?file=std.encryption.class.inc

and following the usage example

http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/showsource.php?file=encryption.php

you can get something like this

http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/encryption.php

Then in your situation you can do this:

```
<form >
<input type="hidden" name="data value="<?php echo($encryptedData); ?>" />
</form>
```

or you could do this

```
<?php setcookie("formdata", $encryptedData, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */ ?>
```

Then on the other end you can decrypt the data using your password.

Comment: My values are set with JS with each event change

Comment: Perhaps an option would be to use "Cryptic" messages like instead of names why not use a property index number? eg. 26=2981

Comment: Or another way, then on top of that you could do some base64'ing to the data. I talked about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147905/how-to-pass-html-tags-to-a-webmethod/6147943#6147943

Comment: Perhaps this might be of interest http://www.starbowconsulting.com/blog/tao/secure-dynamic-forms-and-subforms and more info here: http://groups.drupal.org/node/3540

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, no, not really.

If you give something to the user and get it back, the user can modify it.

Why are you in need of this functionality? If you give us some context, I bet you'll get a definitive answer.