# How to pass html tags to a webmethod?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I'm trying to pass a parameter containing html tags as its value to a webmethod. But it seems not working and i'm only getting the error. Is that possible to do so. Can you suggest any other way to do the same.

```
 htmlContent = htmlContent + document.getElementById("divFollowsTestDiv").innerHTML;
```

// Here im storing the tags and the following method calls the webmethod.

```
    function StoreSessionForHtml(htmlContent) {


        var requesthtmlContentParameter = '{' +
                        'htmlContent:"' + htmlContent + '"}';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Webtop.aspx/HTMLTableContent",
            data: requesthtmlContentParameter,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert("Success", msg.d);
            }, //Event that'll be fired on Success
            error: function() {
                alert("Try Again");

            } //Event that'll be fired on Error
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried html-encoding it?

Comment: you mean to convert all those < > symbols? no

Answer (score 0):

You should URL Encode on the client side and decode on the client side.  essentially it changes "<" to "<".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more stable and safer solution would be to base64 the data before it is sent?
Base 64 will convert the entire string to a strict set of a-zA-Z0-9 and an equals sign.
In ASP you can base64 using this: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=5248

```
// This code was written by Tyler Akins and has been placed in the
// public domain.  It would be nice if you left this header intact.
// Base64 code from Tyler Akins -- http://rumkin.com

var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

function encode64(input) {
    var output = new StringMaker();
    var chr1, chr2, chr3;
    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    while (i < input.length) {
        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
            enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
            enc4 = 64;
        }

        output.append(keyStr.charAt(enc1) + keyStr.charAt(enc2) + keyStr.charAt(enc3) + keyStr.charAt(enc4));
   }

   return output.toString();
}
```